# Logarithmic equation, some variables in bases and in arguments

Tags: logarithms

This is the exercise, there are no clues in the book about it.
$$
40\log_{4x}x^\frac{1}{2}-14\log_{16x}x^3=-\log_{\frac{1}{2}x}x^2
$$

Solutions given by the book: $x=1; x=4; x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$

And this is what I did so far:

1. conditions for existence:
   $$
   \Biggl\{
   \begin{eqnarray} 
   x &\gt& 0.\\
   x &\ne& \frac 14; x \ne \frac{1}{16}; x \ne 2.
   \end{eqnarray}
   $$
2. I simplified some exponent in the arguments:
   $$
   20\log_{4x}x-42\log_{16x}x+2\log_{\frac{1}{2}x}x=0
   $$
3. Change of bases:
   $$
   \frac{20}{\log_x4x}-\frac{42}{\log_x16x}+\frac{2}{\log_x\frac{1}{2}x}=0
   $$
4. Observing that: $\log_xnx=1+\log_xn$
5. least common multiple:
   $$
   \frac{20(1+\log_x16)(1+\log_x\frac12)-42(1+\log_x4)(1+\log_x\frac12)+2(1+\log_x4)(1+\log_x16)}{(1+\log_x16)(1+\log_x4)(1+\log_x\frac12)}=0
   $$
6. denominator can be toggled, as for conditions for existence
7. then I lost confidence in what I was doing...

Any clue is welcome, thanks :]

Comment: Try substituting $u = \log_2{x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use that

$$\log_a^b=\frac{\log a}{\log b}$$

therefore

$$40\log_{4x}x^\frac{1}{2}-14\log_{16x}x^3=-\log_{\frac{1}{2}x}x^2$$

$$40\frac{\log x^\frac{1}{2}}{\log {4x}}-14\frac{\log x^3}{\log {16x}}=-\frac{\log x^2}{\log {\frac{1}{2}x}}$$

$$20\frac{\log x}{\log {x}+\log 4}-42\frac{\log x}{\log {x}+\log 16}=-2\frac{\log x}{\log {x}+\log \frac12}$$

and eliminating $\log x \neq 0$ (which is a solution)

$$\frac{10}{\log {x}+2\log 2}-\frac{21}{\log {x}+4\log 2}=-\frac{1}{\log {x}-\log 2}$$

then let $y=\log x$ and $a=\log 2$ to obtain

$$\frac{10}{y+2a}-\frac{21}{y+4a}+\frac{1}{y-a}=0$$

$$\frac{10(y+4a)(y-a)-21(y+2a)(y-a)+(y+2a)(y+4a)}{(y+2a)(y+4a)(y-a)}=0$$

$$\frac{10(y^2+3ay-4a^2)-21(y^2+ay-2a^2)+(y^2+6ay+8a^2)}{(y+2a)(y+4a)(y-a)}=0$$

$$\frac{-10 y^2+15 ay+10a^2}{(y+2a)(y+4a)(y-a)}=0$$

$$\frac{-5(y-2a)(2y+a)}{(y+2a)(y+4a)(y-a)}=0$$

that is

- $\log x = 2\log 2$
- $2\log x = -\log 2$

Comment: Yes, this is the procedure I'll use for future reference. I'm rewriting it in my notebook, but I'll directly choose to use $\log_2$ in the substitution, because this will simplify a. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Nice, I wanted to try myself. I worked the first step as you did, getting to

$$\frac{20}{\log_x4x}-\frac{42}{\log_x16x}+\frac{2}{\log_x\frac{1}{2}x}=0,$$

*valid if $x\neq 1$, which is anyhow a solution to the original equation*.

Then, dividing by $2$ and rewriting the logarithms as you did, yields

$$\frac{10}{1+\log_x4}-\frac{21}{1+\log_x 16}+\frac1{1-\log_x 2}=0.$$

From here I proceded inverting base and arguments and replacing $\log_{16} x$ with $t$, for simplicity

$$\frac{10}{1+\frac1{2t}}-\frac{21}{1+\frac1{t}}+\frac1{1-\frac1{4t}}=0,$$

which, again for $t\neq 0$, is equivalent to

$$\frac{20}{2t+1}-\frac{21}{t+1}+\frac4{4t-1}=0.$$

Least common denominator brings you to the quadratic equation

$$16t^2-6t-1=0,$$

with the desidered solutions, i.e. $t=\frac12$ and $t=-\frac18$.

Comment: Excellent! That’s the path I was trying hard. Can you please tell where can I find more info on the substitution? It’s not so clear for me that if $\log_{16}x=t$ then $\log_{4}x=2t$. Would it be the same if I had $\log_{16x}x=t$ and $\log_{4x}x=?$

Comment: @sabi if you want to familiarize with logarithm properties, you should recall that they are just *exponents*. So, e.g., if $\log_{16}x = \alpha$ and $\log_4x = \beta$, then $16^\alpha=4^\beta =x$, and from there you derive your identity. I can't think of any book in english that deals with this material, right now. Can you give me reference to the book you got this exercise from?

Comment: https://www.pearson.it/opera/pearson/0-6117-analisi_matematica_i an Italian book.

Comment: @sabi don't worry, I'm Italian, too. If you like, have a look at the exercises I propose www.dfnu.xyz.

Comment: @sabi and by the way, then, a good reference for basic material could be the high school books by Leonardo Sasso.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm already checking your website :]